# Flutter App White Screen(Or crashed) in Release Mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-android, flutter-release

A/flutter: [FATAL:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(22)] Error while initializing the Dart VM: Precompiled runtime requires a precompiled snapshot
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 9712

My flutter app got Crashed in release mode.. instead all working fine in debug mode.
while checking with separate opening android folder in Android studio and run in release mode. I got this issue
"Error while initializing the Dart VM: Precompiled runtime requires a precompiled snapshot".

Version Info that I'm used

```
flutter version : 3.0.5


compileSdkVersion 33
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 33

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
```

Log Cat Data by running separate android folder in android studio by enabling debuggable true in build.gradle.

```html
01/22 00:12:00: Launching 'app' on Pixel 4 API 31.
Install successfully finished in 4 s 839 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.ore/com.ore.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 16685 on device 'Pixel_4_API_31 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/.outreachexper: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/.outreachexper: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10163; state: ENABLED
V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.ore' set to: 'default'
V/GraphicsEnvironment: Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
I/ResourceExtractor: Found extracted resources res_timestamp-1-1674385878848
I/ResourceExtractor: Resource version mismatch res_timestamp-1-1674387737896
I/ResourceExtractor: Extracted baseline resource assets/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin
I/ResourceExtractor: Extracted baseline resource assets/flutter_assets/vm_snapshot_data
I/ResourceExtractor: Extracted baseline resource assets/flutter_assets/isolate_snapshot_data
W/.ore: type=1400 audit(0.0:310): avc: denied { map } for path="/data/data/com.ore/app_flutter/flutter_assets" dev="dm-5" ino=148729 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c163,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c163,c256,c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.ore
A/flutter: [FATAL:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(22)] Error while initializing the Dart VM: Precompiled runtime requires a precompiled snapshot
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 16685 (.ore), pid 16685 (.ore)
W/.ore: type=1400 audit(0.0:311): avc: denied { map } for path="/data/data/com.ore/app_flutter/flutter_assets" dev="dm-5" ino=148729 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c163,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c163,c256,c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.ore
W/.ore: type=1400 audit(0.0:312): avc: denied { read } for name="max_map_count" dev="proc" ino=183138 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c163,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_max_map_count:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.ore
```

Comment: You may want to try `flutter clean` and then build you project again.

Comment: Already did multiple times, but same issue.

Comment: can you run the app with usb attached in android studio and share log cat data?

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh I've added logcat data and updated my question.

Comment: As log cat data show this error `Precompiled runtime requires a precompiled snapshot` please check this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75488

Comment: Already check this issue : I tried, none of the work for me.